# MongoDB average of embedded Array as extra field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My documents looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "53ce85eda2579da8b40c1f0f",
    "name" : "Autokino",
    "tags" : [
        "forMen"
    ],
    "ratings" : [
        { "rating" : 5, "uuid" : "..."},
        { "rating" : 4, "uuid" : "..."},
        { "rating" : 4, "uuid" : "..."},
        { "rating" : 1, "uuid" : "..."},
    ]
}
```

Now I need the average of ratings.rating (here it should be 3.5). My query looks like this:

```
activities.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectID(req.params.id) } },
    { $unwind: '$ratings' },                                                                                                                                                                          
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        rating: { $avg: '$ratings.rating'},
    }},
]);
```

It works, but what I get is:

```
{
  "_id" : "53ce85eda2579da8b40c1f0f",
  "rating" : 3.5
}
```

and this is what I need to get:

```
{
    "_id" : "53ce85eda2579da8b40c1f0f",
    "name" : "Autokino",
    "tags" : [
        "forMen"
    ],
    "rating" : 3.5
}
```

(The original document without ratings array but with rating average)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipeline stages like [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) are "absolute" in that only the declared fields are emitted. You need another operator here. [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) will do:

```
activities.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectID(req.params.id) } },
    { "$unwind": "$ratings" },                                                                                                                                                                          
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "tags": { "$first": "$tags" },
        "rating": { "$avg": "$ratings.rating" },
    }},
]);
```

Since [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) makes many documents out of the array contents de-normalized, you can use `$first` here to just take the "first" occurrence of the additional field that you are not otherwise aggregating.

If you are worried about lots of fields to declare this way MongoDB 2.6 does offer the [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable. I'ts usage and output  are likely not what you really want:

```
activities.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectID(req.params.id) } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$$ROOT",
        "ratings": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$ratings" },                                                                                                                                                                          
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "rating": { "$avg": "$ratings.rating" },
    }},
]);
```

This gives you something like:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id": "53ce85eda2579da8b40c1f0f",
        "name" : "Autokino",
        "tags" : [
            "forMen"
        ],
        "ratings" : [
            { "rating" : 5, "uuid" : "..."},
            { "rating" : 4, "uuid" : "..."},
            { "rating" : 4, "uuid" : "..."},
            { "rating" : 1, "uuid" : "..."},
        ]
    },
    "rating": 3.5
}
```

This is okay here since grouping by `_id` is the same as grouping on the whole document. So you can always add a final `$project` to return to similar state. But there are no wildcards here.

Comment: my documents are big and have many fields, is there something, that let me access the hole document?

Comment: @dkoch In MongoDB 2.6 there is the `$$ROOT` variable but that will only assign to one field even if it is all of the document at the current pipeline stage. You would still need a final `$project` in order to get your original structure back. MongoDB queries are all data structures anyway. In reality to should be generating them rather than hard coding them.

Comment: unwind does not work, because $ratings does not exists after the projection

Comment: @dkoch Typo in the second listing. It was just there for example and you do understand how this is generally not a practical approach I hope.

Comment: I endet up with 2 queries. One for aggregate functions and one normal find.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this whole song and dance as well and ended up having to re-add all my fields back. Not ideal!

So I just found this - much easier: I have a reviews array field, which has a rating property of 1 - 5

```
{
      $addFields: { avg: { $avg: '$reviews.rating'}}
},
```